# GCMRegistrar isRegisteredOnServer

Tags: android

Hi Guys what does GCMRegistrar isRegisteredOnServer Really send? Does it send the Device ID, device name, IP address of the connection etc. to the server or something Else?

For example it may return like GCMRegistrar Is registered on server: true

I know it sends a Registration ID but what does the Registration ID contain, does it include google accounts and such or just a random ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(Context)` is simply a convenience method that checks a locally stored flag (implemented using SharedPreferences) which you can set to true or false using `GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(Context, boolean)`.

You can optionally specify a lifetime for the flag using `GCMRegistrar. setRegisterOnServerLifespan(Context, long)` which will automatically set the flag to false after the specified time period expires. Default lifespan is 7 days, as indicated in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#DEFAULT_ON_SERVER_LIFESPAN_MS).

Comment: Is there anyway to disable the life span to make it unlimited?

Comment: Hey @DanKodi, wouldn't you just use the regualr setRegisteredOnServer and isRegisteredOnServer?